# Find user with specific spring security role

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, spring-security, hql

I have the following:

```
def userInstance=User.findAll("from User u where u.merchant is not null and u.merchant.id = ? and u.authorities.authority.contains('ROLE_MERCHANT')", merchantId)
```

And get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: ( near line 1, column 121 [from com.testing.tests.User u where u.merchant is not null and u.merchant.id = ? and u.authorities.authority.contains('ROLE_MERCHANT')]
    at $Proxy20.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at testing.admin.UserService.findByMerchantId(UserService.groovy:14)
```

How can I return only users that have a specific role?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you take a look at the default implementation of `User#getAuthorities` you will note that the property is itself implemented with a dynamic finder call:

```
UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
```

Therefore you can not refer to `authorities` in the HSQL query, but you can query users with a specific role over the `UserRole` association domain class in multiple ways:

```
def users = UserRole.withCriteria {
   role{
       eq 'authority', 'ROLE_SOMETHING'
   }
   projections{
      property 'user'
   }
}
```

or

```
def users = UserRole.findAllByRole(domainRole)?.user
```

Comment: I am trying the withCriteria version and I get an SQLGrammarException because of `select this_.user_id as y0_ from user_role this_ where (role_alias1_.authority=?)` . I think that role_alias1_ should be this_ (or viceversa) but can't figure out why it's beeing generated like this. Any pointers ?

Comment: this was really helpfull in a problem i was facing just minutes ago, i can follow the logic but i do not get the need of Querying Associations the use of role {...}